# using python suds module to send requests/return responses from wsdl soap service

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to use the python suds module to send requests to a soap service and retrieve results, but am unsure of how to enter in the parameters for the method I want to call. I have been successul in accessing the service and retrieving the methods which show the paramaters and data types, but I haven't had luck in getting a response which I try to send a request. I'm new with this so am unsure of what I am doing wrong. I'm getting this error: `suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'java.rmi.RemoteException'` on the line that initiates the response. I suspect I am not inputting the parameters correctly for the method, but it's not clear to me how to revise it. I want to call the `getPostmileForPoint` method. This is what I have so far:

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client

url = 'http://geo.dot.ca.gov/services/PostmileWebService?wsdl'
client = Client(url)

response = client.service.getPostmileForPoint(inputPoint=[None,None,-119.509444,36,None],options=None,routeAlignment='R',routeNumber=43,routeSuffixCode=None)
print response
```

I used this code below to find the methods in the service along with the parameters they require:

```
for service in client.wsdl.services:
        for port in service.ports:
            methods = port.methods.values()
            for method in methods:
                print(method.name)
                for part in method.soap.input.body.parts:
                    part_type = part.type
                    if(not part_type):
                        part_type = part.element[0]
                    print('  ' + str(part.name) + ': ' + str(part_type))
                    o = client.factory.create(part_type)
                    print('    ' + str(o))
```

And I used this code to get more details on the paramters for the method I am trying to call:

```
method = client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods["getPostmileForPoint"]
params = method.binding.input.param_defs(method)
print params
```

**UPDATE:**
I found a javascript function used on a webpage that calls the web service with the input parameters for the method I want to use. I am now wondering how I can translate this into python using suds (I only included the code from the function that I think is needed, the rest of it does stuff with adding the results to the webpage):

```
function getPostmile()
{
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('latLongResult');  
  var popupHtml = null;

  var req = new revPMRequest();
  var pt = new lrspoint();
  pt.x = parseFloat(document.InputCoordinates.InputX.value);
  pt.y = parseFloat(document.InputCoordinates.InputY.value);
  pt.spatialReferenceID=4269;//NAD83
  var opt = new revPMOptions();
  opt.toleranceDegrees=0.01703; //~1 mile
  req.inputPoint = pt;
  req.options = opt;
  var ws = new GISWebServiceSoapImp();
  var res = ws.getPostmileForPoint(req);
  var pm = res.outputPostmile;
```